# R: grep unintendedly outputs more than a single string match

Tags: r, regex, string, match, lapply

I have a data frame with 1 variable and 5,000 rows, where each element is a string.

```
1. "Am open about my feelings."                   
2. "Work hard"                                 
3. "Work harder than others."
   .....
5000. "Speak softly."
```

I need to find and output row indices that correspond to a number of elements, i.e. one row index per exact matched element. Currently, I use the following function:

```
z <- lapply(df, function(p) {
     grep(pattern = p, test[ , 1])})
```

It works well and outputs row indices for each element I am looking for. But I noticed that it gets greedy so that the code does not only find exact strings but also larger strings that happen to contain the original string. For example, if the code is searching for a row index of element "Work hard.", it will output 2 row indices. One is for the exact match and another is for the larger string containing the original string, "Work harder than others."

```
[1] 2 3
```

So far I only partially solved the problem:

I searched through a large number of grep-related threads on the web-site, and found a solution that works but only for finding the exact match for one string phrase at a time.

```
grep("\\bWork hard*\\b", df$value)
```

Since this is not an efficient solution, I would like to ask for help in adjusting the lapply code to make it find the exact sting only. I also tried adding "\\b" and "*\\b" in various parts of the lapply code, but unsuccessfully.

## EDIT. Reproducible example added

test_1 is the dataframe containing almost 5000 string elements, but for
 a small reproducible example, I will only provide 5 string elements

```
test_1 <- c( 
         "Like to watch children open presents.",         
          "Work hard.",                              
          "Work harder after a failure.",                   
          "Am open about my feelings.",                
          "Show my sadness.")

library(dplyr)

test_1 <- tbl_df(test_1) # tablulate as datafarme
```

df is a character object with 3 string values:

```
df <- c("Work hard.", 
        "Show my sadness.", 
        "Like to watch children open presents.")
```

below is the function that takes each element of df, finds its match in test_1
 and outputs corresponding row indices from test_1

```
j <- lapply(df, function(p) {
grep(pattern = p, test_1[ , 1])})
j

# Output
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 # as you see it finds two matches. One is the exact match: "Work hard." row index 2. Another one is a larger string that contains wording of the original string: row index 3. But I only want an exact match, i.e. index 2

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

What I want: a single row index per each exactly matched element

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

Comment: can you show a small reproduciible example.  What is `test`

Comment: You can paste the word boundaries on each word in your vector `p`

Comment: Thank you, I will post a reproducible example shortly

Comment: If this is a vector, why are you using `lapply`?

Comment: @akrun I added a reproducible example as requested. Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: @Sotos I added a reproducible example as requested. Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with using `lapply` and `grep` you can use the following code:

```
lapply(df, function(z) grep(paste0("^",z,"$"), test_1))
```

The results are

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

This works by using anchors. `^` is the anchor for the start of a string, and `$` is the anchor for the end of a string. Using `paste0` combines the anchors with the string of interest in `df` to create the following:

```
[1] "^Work hard.$"                            "^Show my sadness.$"                      "^Like to watch children open presents.$"
```

and searches the EXACT whole string by restricting the field of search to whatever is between `^` and `$`.